# C++ Binary Tree Printing Nodes

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I'm learning about binary trees. I was looking at Stanford website:
http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/110/BinaryTrees.html
There was a practice problem of making a tree by calling newNode() three times, and using three pointer variables.
The struct and newNode were given. I was trying to print out the nodes.

```
struct node { 
    int data; 
    struct node* left; 
    struct node* right; 
} ;

/* 
 Helper function that allocates a new node 
 with the given data and NULL left and right pointers. 
*/ 
struct node* newNode(int data) { 
  struct node* node = new(struct node); 
  node->data = data; 
  node->left = NULL; 
  node->right = NULL;

  return(node); 
}; 

// call newNode() three times 
struct node* build123a() { 
  struct node* root = newNode(2); 
  struct node* lChild = newNode(1); 
  struct node* rChild = newNode(3);
  root->left = lChild; 
  root->right= rChild;

  return(root); 
}

int main() {

    struct node* test = build123a();
    cout << "root: " << test->data << endl;
    cout << "left: " << test->left << endl;
    cout << "right: " << test->right << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The issue is that this prints out only the integer in root.
For the left and right nodes, it prints out address locations. 
My knowledge of pointers is still a little shaky. But it shouldn't matter that I've only returned root right? newNode is a pointer to a node right?
Just looking for a simple fix to print out left and right nodes.

Comment: Draw the structure on a paper, with circles as the nodes and pointers as arrows to the other nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct node { 
    int data; // the actual data contained inside this node
    struct node* left; // a node pointer that points to the left child
    struct node* right; // a node pointer that points to the right child
};

struct node* test; // is a node pointer
test->left; // is a node pointer that points to the left child of test
test->right; // is a node pointer that points to the right child of test

cout << test->data; // prints the integer contained within the test node
cout << test->left; // prints the address of the left child of test since it's a pointer
cout << test->right; // prints the address of the right child of test since it's a pointer
```

What you want to do is print the data contained within the left and right children.

```
cout << test->left->data;
cout << test->right->data;
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because 'left' & 'right' **are** pointers.

To print out the 'data' of the left or right, change the code as follows:

cout << "left: " << test->left->data << endl;

cout << "right: " << test->right->data << endl;

Note, however, if left or right are NULL (i.e., zero) you'll likely get a memory access exception.

Answer (score 1):

`test->left` is `(*test).left` which is of type `struct node*`.

To print the data in `left` you need

```
cout << (test -> left -> data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can print "test->data" correctly because that's an int. The issue is that "test->left" and "test->right" are pointers, and pointers are basically numbers that refer to where another object is stored.

If you wanted to print the left node's data, you'd have to do this:

```
cout << "left: " << test->left->data << endl;
```

And then you'd have to do the same for the right node.